# How to redirect to a filename in my directory?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to do a simple javascript game and this is the code for loading next level after completation of the previous one. I was expecting it to check what is the current level and based on that skip to the next level. It's not working properly. Actually it seems that the first two if statements are working but I can't say the same for the last one: it does nothing.

```js
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
        if(location.pathname==="/level0.html"){
          location.assign("/level1.html")   
        }
        if(location.pathname==="/level1.html"){
          location.assign("/level2.html")   
        }
        if(location.pathname==="/level2.html"){        
          location.assign("/level3.html")   
        }        
    })
```

```css
/*some css here*/
```

```html
<button id="next">NEXT LEVEL</button>
```

I even tried to use "else if" statements but it's not working neither.

```js
        if(location.pathname==="/level0.html"){
          location.assign("/level1.html")   
        }
        else if(location.pathname==="/level1.html"){
          location.assign("/level2.html")   
        }
        else if(location.pathname==="/level2.html"){        
          location.assign("/level3.html")   
        }
        else{
          location.assign("/index.html")
        }
```

I also read the documentation about location property but I don't understand where could be the problem.
Can someone help me understand please?

Thanks

Comment: what if you just set global variables like `var level = 1` and then load it with `location.assign('level' + level + '.html');`

Comment: You should check if it "contains" instead of ===, that is very strict checking, you just might want to check the pattern. Sometimes it can have slashes sometimes not.

Comment: @bmeers5 it's the same thing, isn't? I understand that probably it's a better choice to use variables, but should be the same I guess

Comment: @user1735921 I cannot use "contains" because location.pathname.contains is not a function in that case. Btw I tried, but nothing works

Comment: obviously contains is not a method, I meant you need to check if it "contains" that pattern

Comment: Ah okok, sorry @user1735921. Btw sure it contains that pattern, I already checked that.

Comment: Add logs and breakpoint and then check what is happening.

Comment: I tried but it is not triggering the event "mouseup", because even console.log is not showing when I click

Comment: @Gu160 could very well be a work around, however I'm interested in seeing if you can figure this one out. I would try to just get the file path first. try using `console.log(document.currentScript.src.toString());`

on another note, do you have source code? That would help with testing

Comment: @bmeers5 I'm not sure I understood. Do I have to try this console.log() in developers tools? Do u mean the whole source code? Yes I can upload it on GitHub and link it here if u need it

Comment: @Gu160 yep! Easy as pressing f12 or ctrl+shift+I and going to the console. Your logs should show up there.

Comment: This command console.log(document.currentScript.src.toString()); solved my issue! I love you ahahah, thank you so much. I'm sorry if I used your time for such a stupid error: I just forgot to load the script.js in the last html file.

Comment: @Gu160 I would go ahead and create an answer for this so that others can find it. Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

There's no particular reason that code shouldn't work, as far as I can tell, but you could simplify it significantly by doing something like this. It will reduce reliance on querying the page's URL, which might conceivably be a point of failure:

```js
var level = 0 // or whichever page's level

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  level++
  location.assign(level > 3 ? '/' : `/level${level}`)
})
```

Comment: I tried your code and I'll thank you for your time, but still this code is "working" as mine... so it's not working for the level3.html

Comment: If you open the developer tools do you see any errors in the console when you're clicking to go to level three? If not, is it possible that another element on the page is overlaying your button and preventing it from being properly clicked? Put a console statement above location.assign to test if it's firing.

Comment: I tried to look at the console and I see no errors when I click the button. I can also say that for sure the button is been clicked because I have an hover effect and it's being triggered correctly

Comment: I'd still put a console statement in there and see if it fires when you click. Either way you'll know better where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of classes and data attributes instead of hard coding a path in the code base.  This allows you to modify one without altering the others, or to add one in the middle for example.  Here I show buttons that would have been on different pages but for illustration, I disable the ones not on a "page" instead of navigating to that page.  The script would be the same on every page as I have it commented out.  IN theory, this could be a link `<a href="newpage.html">Next</a>` instead of a button.

See the second example for a single page and simplified script (could be even simpler if you use an ID but to be consistent, I used the same code cut down.

```js
var nextButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('fun-button');
var showaction = document.getElementById('showaction');
showaction.textContent = "start here";

function nextThing(event) {
  let me = event.target;
  // this is the important line:
  //document.location.href = "/myfolder/"+ event.target.dataset.nextone + ".html"
  // just to show how they are/can be used
  me.disabled = true;
  me.classList.remove("targeted-button");
  console.log(event.target.dataset.nextone);
  let newBtn = document.getElementsByClassName(event.target.dataset.newtarget)[0];
  newBtn.disabled = false;
  newBtn.classList.add("targeted-button");
  showaction.textContent = "I would have called:" + event.target.dataset.nextone + ".html";

}
var testBtns = Array.prototype.filter.call(nextButtons, function(testElement) {
  return testElement.addEventListener('click', nextThing);
});
```

```css
#mybuttons {
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fun-button {
  background-color: #00dddd;
  border: solid 2px #00ff00;
  padding: .5em;
}

.fun-button:disabled {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.fun-button.targeted-button {
  background-color: #dddd00;
}
```

```html
<div>All these would be on different pages:</div>
  <div id="mybuttons">
    <button id="next" class="targeted-button fun-button target-0" data-newtarget="target-1" data-level="0" data-nextone="level1">ON to level 1</button>
    <button class="fun-button target-1" data-newtarget="target-2" data-level="1" data-nextone="level2" disabled>ON to level 2</button>
    <button class="fun-button target-2" data-newtarget="target-3" data-level="2" data-nextone="level3" disabled>ON to level 3</button>
    <button class="fun-button target-3" data-newtarget="target-master" data-level="3" data-nextone="masterlevel" disabled>ON to level 4</button>
    <button class="fun-button target-master" data-newtarget="target-0" data-level="4" data-nextone="level0" disabled>ON back</button>
  </div>

  <div id="showaction">empty me</div>
```

Single page script:

```js
var nextButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('fun-button');
function nextThing(event) {
  let me = event.target;
  console.log("Off we go to "+"/myfolder/"+ event.target.dataset.nextone + ".html");
  // this is the important line:
  document.location.href = "/myfolder/"+ event.target.dataset.nextone + ".html";
}
var testBtns = Array.prototype.filter.call(nextButtons, function(testElement) {
  return testElement.addEventListener('click', nextThing);
});
```

```html
<div id="mybuttons">
    <button id="next" class="targeted-button fun-button target-0" data-newtarget="target-1" data-level="0" data-nextone="level1">ON to level 1</button>
</div>
```